# Changing nexus servers: Maven deploy still deploys to old server

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, nexus

I have copied all contents from an old Nexus server to a new server.  I am able to login to the new server, see all the uploaded artifacts, etc.

On the Jenkins build master, the maven builds are running obviously as the jenkins user. The home directory for that user is /var/lib/jenkins.  Under there, I have copied the .m2 folder and changed all the old URL's in the settings.xml to point to the new URL.

However, when I run a maven deploy, while the build downloads some dependencies from the new nexus server, at the end of the build comes the mvn-deploy plugin and that tries to upload to the old server.

Do the artifacts, war, jar files have a record of the nexus server? Is there some setting in Jenkins that I'm missing?  I did a grep for the old nexus address in /var/lib/jenkins folder and none of the config xml's have any mention of the old nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Is the URL hardcoded in your pom? Maybe the pom is not using the params you set in the settings.xml?

Comment: Nope.  I looked at several pom files.  They have no mention of nexus, IP address, etc.

Comment: Check your jenkins settings.xml The nexus url would probably be listed there. What is the 
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
        ...
        </repository>
 </distributionManagement>
data in your pom?

Its not possible that your code is being sent to the repo if that repo is not specified somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

The repositories configured in the `settings.xml` are the source of Maven artifacts.  The destination for new artifacts is in the `distributionManagement` block.  This is usually somewhere in your POM, or in a parent POM.  The block will look something like the below.  Chances are, the old URL is there.

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Release Repository</name>
        <url>${repository.url}/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>${repository.url}/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```